# Progress dialog + dialog box

Tags: javascript, android

I have a webview that has progress dialog showing:

```
public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
    if (progressDialog == null) 
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading... ");
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

The page i'm loading has a button controlled by javascript that has a dialog box:

```
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("Are You sure?")
    if (answer) {
        alert("No information saved!")
        window.history.go(-2);
    }
    else {
        alert("You may hit save to submit information")
    }
}
```

The issue is when i hit this button, nothing ever happens. If I remove the progress dialog. The button functions very well. I added

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

But there's no luck at all. Have anyone encountered this? How do I solve it?

Comment: `ProgressDialog` is 'system modal' which means whilst it's visible, it is stealing focus from the underlying `WebView`. As a result, the button click isn't being activated. What is the button on the page supposed to do? In other words, why do you need to click it when the `ProgressDialog` is visible?

Comment: It's a cancel button, that would just skip to the home page if a user decide not to fill in the form. Do you know if any other way? like making the progress dialog shows up at first page then vanish for good. OR another way for implementing progressbar(normal). I've seen a guy who did something similar. In his xml layout progressbar (normal) is there but not webview. then he simply          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
         setProgressBarVisibility(true);
         setContentView(R.layout.prog);  where prog is the layout that has the progressbar only.

Comment: Without fully understanding your code, it's difficult to say but you could try something like that. Alternatively, a custom dialog with a `ProgressBar` and a cancel button. If the cancel button is pressed, you can then call `loadUrl("javascript:confirmation()")` on your `WebView`.